# Let X denote a normed space and $Y \subset X$. Denote $Perp(Y) = \{f \in dual(X) : f|_Y = 0\}$. Then Perp(Y) is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis

Recall Dual(X) is the set of continuous linear functionals. Here is my proof. Suppose that $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 1} \subset Perp(Y)$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$. We want to show that $f \in Perp(Y)$.

Fix $y \in Y$. Consider the constant sequence $\{y\}$. What I want to show that $f_n(y) \rightarrow f(y)$ then I would be done because $f_n(y) = 0$ for all n. However, I am not sure how I should approach that.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\|f_n(y)-f(y)\|\leq \|f_n-f\|_{op}\|y\|$ which shows your claim.

Another proof is that $\|f\big\vert_Y\|_{op}\leq \|f\|_{op}$, so the restriction map is continuous and its kernel is $Perp(Y)$.
We can assume that $Y$ is a subspace because $Perp(Y) = Perp(span(Y))$.

Comment: I really liked the second proof very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another proof:  Consider the canonical embedding $J:X\to Dual(Dual(X))$ given by
$$J(x)(f)=f(x).$$
Observe that 
$$ Perp(Y)=\bigcap_{y\in Y}\ker(J(y)), $$ 
so $Perp(y)$ is  an intersection of closed subspaces of $Dual(Y)$, hence it is closed.